# Can you kill the birds?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In New Vegas, every now and again I'll see a friendly on the radar, but I can't target it in VATS. Then as I move closer to it, small black birds fly away. I know they're present just for flavor, but ... if I had a gun, would I be able to shoot and kill them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can kill them, in V.A.T.S they are not targetable but if you shoot on them by aiming manually they will die.. and give you 1XP ;)